# How do I obtain GeoTagging Info from an uploaded image

Tags: php, image-uploading, geotagging

I'd like to build an app that takes (with permission of course) user-uploaded images and makes use of the geotagging info embedded in the image.  I'm a PHP/Javascript developer...how do I obtain that info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cameras generally use exif headers to store GPS information.

With PHP, [the EXIF module](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.exif.php) allows you to read these headers.

To activate this extension, you must compile PHP with --enable-exif.

Comment: Ok, thanks Benjamin.  I just checked my php info page, and exif is "enabled"...can you point me in the direction of any sort of example on how to actually use it?  Thanks!

Comment: Actually...this link (http://rakaz.nl/2007/01/having-fun-with-geotagged-photos.html) has me off and running.  Thanks again,